# Drupal Modules can no longer Enable/Disable

Tags: drupal, module

Drupal 7.21/7.22

I am testing drupal out so I can be considered a newbie.

I have downloaded and install at least a dozen modules enabled them disabled them and all was well until today. I downloaded the References module and soon realized it could not be enabled. It is not specific to this module. No modules can be enabled/disabled.

No error messages.
No log messages.
All dependencies are enabled.
Status report okay.
SimpleTest Enable/Disable Modules did not highlighted any issues.

I upgraded to 7.22, i rebooted the server but nothing helps.
There is almost nothing on the web about this issue so it might be my configuration but I do not know how to debug/isolate this issue.

TIA

Comment: Does deleting the references module from the command line resolve your issue?

Comment: Using drush I am able to enable/disable modules. I removed References i.e. uninstalled it and removed the folder but the Module UI fails to enable/disable.